# Using an unsigned int to terminate a while() loop

Tags: while-loop, unsigned-integer

Is it possible to terminate a while() loop with an unsigned int?  For example I want to terminate a while() when the user enters a negative value.  But I want it to be any negative value, not just -1.

Comment: How would your `unsigned int` store a signed value such as `-1`?

Comment: Well, "what have you tried"? How can it be modified, if needed, to include a larger range? How can this be handled/checked with an *unsigned* int (no negative numbers, by definition) -- and would it be simpler just to handle it as a *signed* type?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: Well I guess it would be simpler with a signed int type instead.  Got things backwards there.

Comment: This is in the C language.  Yes I'm a newbie at this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I think this is a good idea but, in C at least, you can check if your unsigned integer is greater than `INT_MAX` (for two's complement anyway, not so sure about the sign/magnitude and one's complement variants but they're probably rare enough that you could safely ignore them until a problem pops up).

This is, of course, assuming it was read in as an integer and converted to unsigned somewhere - if you use customised input routines expecting only unsigned numbers, they may barf at the presence of a leading `-` sign.